# Fast way to evaluate the PDF of a multivariable distribution

Tags: performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I'm trying to  evaluate the PDF of a truncated  multi-normal distribution.
My distribution has 8 dimensions and each value must be ≥ 0.

```
ivalues = {1.03371, 0.617498, 1.26354, 0.855324, 0.408308, 0.158506, 1.70032,0.269946}
covariancematrix = IdentityMatrix[8]  
truncate = Table[{0, \[Infinity]}, 8]
TruncatedDistribution[truncate,MultinormalDistribution[ivalues, covariancematrix]]
```

So I sampled one set of random values (rvalues) from this distribution using RandomVariate

```
rvalues= {1.13594, 0.641371, 1.31146, 0.915561, 0.327869, 0.225612, 1.44007, 0.268547}
```

Now I want to evaluate the PDF at rvalues

```
PDF[TruncatedDistribution[truncate,MultinormalDistribution[ivalues, covariancematrix]],
      rvalues] // AbsoluteTiming

{0.150935, 0.00037916}
```

It takes about 0.15 seconds.
Since I need to do a lot of this calculations (hundreds of thousands) mi script is runnnig very slow.

Is there any faster way of obtaining this PDF?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Just evaluate the PDF symbolically *first*, then feed the values to that - I get many thousands per second on a netbook, certainly over 100K/s on a real machine....

Comment: Hi Ciao, I forgot to mention that the distribution might move during the iterations. Would this method work if I'm constantly changing my ivalues? Could you write the answer (and a code if you like) in the answer section? Thanks

Comment: @BPinto - I'll add a quick-and-dirty (as in not pretty code) answer as an expample so you get the idea (sorry, busy right now so it will be short and to the point). BTW - I just happened to see your message - without the "@" I was not notified, so sorry for delay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per my comment. Assume things not defined here were as in your example:

```
myDist = TruncatedDistribution[truncate, 
   MultinormalDistribution[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}, 
    covariancematrix]];

myPDF[{a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, h_}, {i_, j_, k_, l_, m_, n_, o_, 
    p_}] = N@PDF[myDist, {i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p}];
```

Just call myPDF with the lists of current *ivalues* and *rvalues*.

E.g, using some random values (here *dist* was already defined):

```
rvals = RandomVariate[dist, 2000];
ivalues = RandomReal[{0, 2}, {2000, 8}];
```

Doing

```
MapThread[myPDF, {ivalues, rvals}]
```

is ~2000x faster on an old netbook vs calling your PDF on each set. S/B even faster I'd venture on a real machine.

Hope that's useful, again sorry for brevity of exposition.

Edit: Note use of *N@* on the PDF - gives a little extra boost by keeping things machine precision. Remove if you are inputting and expect as output arbitrary precision.

Answer (score 3):

If your real covariance matrix is the identity matrix, then all 8 of the random variables are independent and there's no need for the overhead of dealing with a general structure for a multivariate normal.  You can construct the truncated distributions separately, generate a random sample from each, and then multiply the 8 probability densities together.

```
ivalues = {1.03371, 0.617498, 1.26354, 0.855324, 0.408308, 0.158506, 1.70032, 0.269946};
d = Map[TruncatedDistribution[{0, \[Infinity]}, NormalDistribution[#, 1]] &, ivalues];
rvalues = Map[RandomVariate, d];
(* Using rvalues from original question *)
rvalues = {1.13594, 0.641371, 1.31146, 0.915561, 0.327869, 0.225612, 1.44007, 0.268547}

Timing[Times @@ MapThread[PDF, {d, rvalues}]]
(* {0.00205371, 0.00635803} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, I've tried that one but the result is not the same. As you can see I've got 0.00037916 and you 0.0008101343010582806.

Comment: You're welcome.  You might attempt to convince @ciao to write up his comment as an answer as that is a much better general solution than mine.

Comment: My result is different because I used a new random value of `rvalues`.  I'll change it to the values you used.

Comment: @BPinto.  Not sure where you get the value of 0.00037916.  When I run your code and my code with the same values for ivalues and rvalues, I get 0.00635803 for both.